# Is it possible to serialize a datagridview (properties not data) to XML?

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, datagridview

I am in the process of building an application that allows the user to create fully customizable report templates (images, charts, and tables: made with dgvs) by essentially dragging and dropping various charts and tables onto a canvas. All of these charts and tables are populated by a database each time the app is run.

I originally thought about using SQLite to save and restore all possible properties of the controls, but that has turned out to be a bit impractical due to the sheer amount of properties and property types. So, I stumbled on the Microsoft charts `.Serializer` function which allows you to save all chart properties to XML with just a few lines of code. It works great!

However, `datagridviews` do not seem to have such a wonderful built in serialization function. Does anyone know if it is possible to do the same thing (or similar thing) with `datagridviews` as the chart serialization in a way that is practical and logical? I have read several articles about serializing dgv data, but none about serializing the properties.

Comment: Take a look at [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Just create a descendant and then add serialization attributes...

Comment: I have tried several different things up to this point. Unfortunately with each attempt I write over the previous code. The most recent thing I tried is the following:     System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer s = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(lossSumGrid.GetType());
            FileStream stream = new FileStream(exeDir + "\\Test.xml", FileMode.Create);
            s.Serialize(stream, lossSumGrid);

Comment: Okay, so I have never posted code on this site before so I apparently don't know how to do that in the proper, readable way. I apologize.

Comment: The code above results in an error message: "NotSupportedException: Cannot serialize member System.ComponentModel.Component.Site of type System.ComponentModel.ISite because it is an interface." It appears that datagridviews may not have been made with serializing in mind, either that or I am simply going about it in the wrong way.